# ASP.NET authentication session

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have many sites under one ASP.NET forms authentication. They have mixed frameworks (some have 2.0, some 4.0, but it is all fine) Everything works fine, but sometimes, after a random time (for example two minutes) the session on the client ends, and he has to enter his password agian. Why? What am I missing?

Here is part of my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" ><forms loginUrl="../web/start_page/start_page.aspx"
    name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" 
    protection="All"  
    path="/" 
    timeout="60" /></authentication>  
<machineKey
  validationKey="blablabla"
  validation="SHA1" />
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateNetworkTimeout="3600" />
```

Event Viewer shows:

```
Event code: 4005 
Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied    has expired. 
Event time: 21.09.2010 8:23:26 
Event time (UTC): 21.09.2010 4:23:26 
Event ID: e3a00bef332a4dec9cd1aa078a3d5aa4 
Event sequence: 277 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 50202
```

Comment: did you look at the cookie in firebug to see what the 'expires' is set to?

Comment: maybe the server clocks on the sites are out of sync? check the date on them, and the date on the client machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because session time out event occurs so you need to increase your session time something like this

```
<configuration>
  <sessionstate 
      mode="inproc"
      cookieless="false" 
      timeout="20" 
      sqlconnectionstring="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<user id>;password=<password>"
      server="127.0.0.1" 
      port="42424" 
  />
</configuration>
```

Timeout. This option controls the length of time a session is considered valid. The session timeout is a sliding value; on each request the timeout period is set to the current time plus the timeout value

Comment: so i have timeout=60, why doesnt it fits?

Comment: @eba -- check the timeout propety on more detail on msdn to increase your time out

Comment: sessionstate config has nothing to do with forms authentication cookie timeouts.

Comment: @RPM1984 - as per me he gets logged out because of session time out only form the site

Comment: i dont understand your comment, sorry. the point im trying to make is session is server-side (adding a shopping cart, session["cart"] = cart;). the expiry of this item is done by your above answer. but forms auth cookie is client-side, the expiry is done by forms timeout=60, which he has. forms authentication cookie != session.